# Salesforce Web to Case spams

Tags: email2case, web2case

I would like to filter spam emails during web to case & email to case. Please let me know if you have any recommendations or suggestions to handle it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have suggested, we also use validation rules to block spam. In web-to-lead forms, and I imagine in web-to-case as well, etc. when a validation rule fails then that lead/case won't be created. That's one way to block the spam. An administrator user will likely receive an email alert for every validation failure through the web forms. I simply setup an email filter rule to keep those notices out of my inbox.

I like @girbot idea of routing "possible spam" to a separate queue via assignment rules then auto deleting after X time to allow a human to do a gut check.

If validation rules and assignment rules are not sufficient then you may need to add custom app development where your forms actually submit to one of your servers that you can assert Captcha or other spam blocking techniques then forward the request to salesforce to create the lead/case. This obviously is the more involved approach but would provide the most strength.

Answer (score 4):

When first starting to deal with incoming spam via web to lead or case, I always start with these suggestions - https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-to-resolve-Web-to-X-Spam-issues-1327109135974&language=en_US.

Once those are exhausted though, I've used a variety of more complex fixes, usually not on the salesforce side.

Answer (score 1):

Put as much pressure on your it department or whoever is in control of your anti spam appliance. Also we use the assignment rules to assign the cases to spam queues but this comes with maintenance.  We use a mixture of whitelisting rules and blacklisting rules assigning to genuine queues for the white lists and to a spam queue for the black list. This means the users don't get see the spam unless they go to a spam queue to clear it out.

Then we use a scheduled class that deletes any case closed as spam over 30 days ago. This allows the spam queues to be checked by a human before they get auto deleted.